# JavaScript event handling timing

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I got the following problem. Could you please help?

1. Have an event handler EH1 on `onload` event of body.
2. This event handler EH1 adds a new DOM element by calling a helper function HF1.
3. Then the event handler EH1 changes the value of the new element.
4. The event handler EH1 then call another helper function HF2 to calculate the output based on the new element.

In IE and Firefox, if an alert is inserted between step 2 and 3. The output would be correct. If no alert is inserted, the output would be incorrect, as if the helper function HF2 in step 4 cannot see the value of the new element.

In Chrome or Opera, the alert does not help.

Comment: Can you show this code please?

Comment: I am not sure if I can show the code :(. I guess that's because HF1 uses ajax async call. Before the call returns, step 3 has no effect. I guess in IE/FF,  the alert allow HF1 ajax async call to return and update the DOM. While in Chrome/Opera, the alert blocks everything.  I removed the ajax async call in HF1 and the code appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

Perform your actions on DOMReady instead of onload at body.

Comment: I cannot decide which event to listen on.　Can only modify the event handler. Also not clear to me why DOMReady would make a difference.  IMO, 'Onload" loads imiges and DOMReady does not.

Comment: Could we actually see the helper functions and event handlers?